# Using rails migration generator to add foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

```
rails 4.2.4
ruby 2.2.1
```

To auto generate the countries migration, I would do:

```
rails g migration CreateCountry abbreviation:string status:string search_operations_id:integer
```

I would like to add a foreign key to the generated migration file:

```
add_foreign_key :countries, :search_operations, on_delete: :cascade
```

How can I do that using a rails g migration command?

Comment: Honestly I don't know if this can be done with a generator, but I do know that Rails' generators can't do everything that you might want in a migration.  Why not manually add the `add_foreign_key` statement after generating the migration?

Comment: Yes, I am aware I can manually add it. That's what I do now. I am looking for an automated short cut to do it that's less complicated than generated an empty migration file and then adding the statement to it

Comment: You can do it using an automated migration, but `on_delete: :cascade` option you need to add manually. Rails generator don't support add all options to add from command lines.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding the search_operations_id manually in your migration, you could actually just say:

```
rails g migration CreateCountry ... search_operations:references
```

When Rails generates the migration, you should see something like this:

```
class CreateCountry < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    ...
    add_reference :countries, :search_operations, index: true
    add_foreign_key :countries, :search_operations
  end
end
```

Comment: The on_delete :cascade will not be there, and this actually produces a t.references :search_operations, index: true, foreign_key: true to the migration the objective is to delete the countries that belong to search_operation when search_operation is deletred

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately... I don't think you'll be able to get the on_delete :cascade without adding that in manually...